# Netty concatenates messages that arrive simultaneously

Tags: java, tcp, byte, arrays, netty

I have one client connected to a server. The communication in the TCP session is bidirectional. If I try to send multiple messages simultaneously from the sever to the client they are mixed up in one array. The message is already corrupted when it reaches the ByteArrayDecoder. Here is my pipeline:

```
    ChannelPipeline channelPipeline = ch.pipeline();

    channelPipeline.addLast("byteArrayEncoder", new ByteArrayEncoder());
    channelPipeline.addLast("myRequestEncoder", new MyRequestEncoder());
    channelPipeline.addLast("mySecondEncoder", new MySecondEncoder());

    channelPipeline.addLast("byteArraydDecoder", new ByteArrayDecoder());
    channelPipeline.addLast("myResponseDecoder", new MyResponseDecoder());
    channelPipeline.addLast("mySecondDecoder", new MySecondDecoder());

    channelPipeline.addLast("mytHandler", myHandler);
```

For example I have noticed that the byte array in ByteArrayDecoder has length more than 500 instead of 230. And I have seen that the contents of the array are corresponding to two or more messages that have been concatenated.

I have only one channel. I have tried to use more than one EventExecutorGroup in the pipeline but this keeps happening and I end up to miss several inbound messages.

However with 1tps everything seems to work OK.

Is netty supposed to have such behavior? Am I missing anything?

Comment: TCP should coalse data sent at around the same time.  You need to implement a protocol which can determine where one message ends and the next one starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP is a stream based protocol, you application should work from that concept. Netty also receives the bytes as a stream from the networking layer, and its the job of the application to convert the stream of bytes in something useful.

You are failing to correctly convert the incoming streaming bytes in correct blocks of data that your application can handle.

There are multiple ways to introduce a "reframer" for the bytes:

### Make every packet a fixed length

If every packet is a fixed length, you can just read `X` amount of bytes, and use that as a simple framing solution, this is really simple using netty:

```
channelPipeline.addLast("framer", new FixedLengthFrameDecoder(512));
```

This splits all the incoming bytes up in blocks of 512 bytes.

The arguments to [`FixedLengthFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/index.html?io/netty/handler/codec/FixedLengthFrameDecoder.html) are:

- Length of the incoming packets

### Prepend the length of the packet before sending

Instead of difficulty making every packet the same size, you can also add a length to a packet, so you can split the packets later. Netty also comes with useful utility classes for this:

```
channelPipeline.addLast("framer", new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(Short.MAX_VALUE,0,2,0,2));
channelPipeline.addLast("framer-prepender", new LengthFieldPrepender(2, false));
```

The arguments for [`LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.html) are:

- Max frame length
- Offset in receiving data for frame length
- Length in bytes of our length field
- Bytes to strip from the received message

The arguments for [`LengthFieldPrepender`](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/LengthFieldPrepender.html) are:

- Length in bytes of our length field

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I am rather ignorant regarding socket programming in general. So you are saying that if I use frame decoders I will not loose any messages I will rather simply split my messages and then they will be dispatched to the next decoder properly? The first 4 bytes of every message are reserved for its length so somehow I need to use this.

Comment: @ampofila So the existing messages already have a length attached on them? In that case you can use the LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder to split them without using the encoder, I believe the following options would work correctly: `Integer.MAX_VALUE, 0, 4, 0, 0`. I also recommend that you read the [paragraph over stream based decoding in the netty documentation](http://netty.io/wiki/user-guide-for-4.x.html#dealing-with-a-stream-based-transport), as it gives a even better explanation how to solve this problem

Comment: I am still testing this but for now it does not work. It works for only one or two requests then my client does nothing. I have 4 types of messages, the first 3 have a fixed length while the 4th does not. Also I noticed that it takes more time to read the messages. My byte order is LITTLE_ENDIAN (I set it in the constructor), does this matter?

Comment: @ampofila I have a hard time helping you without understating how the underlying protocol works, what kind of messages are there, and do you have any documentation of them?

Comment: Nevermind, with your original post and a good night's sleep I managed to get it working properly. My dummy server was sending incorrect length in the message header so LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder worked fine. Thank you very much.